# averaging by months with daily data

Tags: r, average

I have daily data with my matrix, divided into 6 columns -  "Years, months, days, ssts, anoms, missing ".

[image]

I want to calculate the average of each month of SST in each year. (For example - 1981 - september - avg values sts of all days in sept), and I want to do the same for all the years. i am trying to work, my code, but am unable to do so.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when you could more easily cut and paste the text into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `dplyr` package in R. For this, we will call your data `df`

```
require(dplyr)

df.mnths <- df %>% 
            group_by(Years, months) %>%
            summarise(Mean.SST = mean(SSTs))

df.years <- df %>%
            group_by(Years) %>%
            summarise(Mean.SST = mean(SSTs))
```

This is two new data sets that will have the `mean(SST)` for each month of each year in `df.mnths`, and another dataset that will have `mean(SST)` for all years in `df.years`.

Comment: Consider the change: `SST->SSTs`

Comment: Completed the request. Hope this is more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of `data.table` you can perform the following action

```
library(data.table)
dt[, average_sst := mean(SSTs), by = .(years,months)]
```

adding an extra column `average_sst`.

Answer (score 0):

just suppose that your data is stored in a data.frame named "data":

```
years months        SSTs
1  1981      1 -0.46939368
2  1981      1  0.03226932
3  1981      1 -1.60266798
4  1981      1 -1.53095676
5  1981      1  1.71177023
6  1981      1 -0.61309846

tapply(data$SSTs, list(data$years, data$months), mean)
tapply(data$SSTs, factor(data$years), mean)
```